# Change chart markers size

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have a scatter graph that picks up a variable range of cells from a pivot (no problems here).

I want each of the scatter markers to be enlarged. I have the following VBA code.

```
'Remove all the old data points.    
    For Each srs In Groupcht.SeriesCollection
        srs.Delete
    Next
'Set the data points
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Row = 7 To lastrow
        Set srs = Groupcht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With srs
            .Values = Cells(Row, 2)
            .XValues = Cells(Row, 3)
            .Name = Cells(Row, 1)
            .MarkerSize = 15 'This should change the Marker size for each NEW plot.
        End With

    Next Row
```

One maybe two of the points will have the desired marker size on event update, and on the rare occasion all of them format to size 15.

I am on Windows 10. With Office 365.

Comment: Question - `.Value = Cells(Row, 2)` - that's just one point? Don't you want an entire series?

Comment: It loops through 7 to lastrow and sets row to the interger. i get all the points and the data is correct. its just the markersize. @BigBen

Comment: So you have a series for *each individual point*?

Comment: Side note - don't use `Integer`, use `Long`.

Comment: yes, i need the legend to show me a name for each point. hence why i set the name as well

Comment: Ok just making sure - this is not what I would think of when I think scatter plot and I don't have your chart in front of me. What `event` are we talking about?

Comment: unable to share the pic of the graph, but its more like a 2 by 2 graph with axis in the middle with about 10 ish points. each point needs its own label x and y. hence why i create a new series for each point.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AWN0p3N is the link, remembered my password!, and its on Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate

Comment: @bigBen after looking closely it's the first and last series with the enlarged data points? Thats odd to me

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here.

You need to go within the .Points(pointIndex) Property and change the settings there.

```
Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Row = 7 To lastrow
        Set srs = Groupcht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With srs
            .Values = Cells(Row, 2)
            .XValues = Cells(Row, 3)
            .Name = Cells(Row, 1)
            With .Points(1)
                .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
                .MarkerSize = 15
            End With
        End With
    Next Row
```